# Transformation error when running OData v4 Client Code Generator

Tags: c#, odata

I have an OData service that returns the following from the `/$metadata` endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
    <Schema Namespace="(...)" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
      <!-- ... -->
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

When I attempt to run the [OData v4 Client Code Generator (v2.3.0)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937) against this XML file, I get the following errors:

> Warning: Running transformation: The element 'edmx:Edmx' was unexpected for the root element. The root element should be Edmx.
>
> Warning: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata:DataServiceVersion' attribute is not declared.

I also see only an empty `.cs` output file.

I've tried removing the `edmx:` namespace prefix from the `<Edmx>` and `<DataServices>` elements, making that namespace the default, and adjusting the prefixes on the remaining elements, but that doesn't work either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:edm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
  <DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
    <edm:Schema Namespace="(...)">
      <!-- ... -->
    </edm:Schema>
  </DataServices>
</Edmx>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it looks like the problem might be the version of OData that the service is exposing -- namely, **OData v1.0**. The `edm` namespace being defined is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm`. See [OData Version 4.0 Part 3: Common Schema Definition Language (CSDL), §2.2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406397923):

> Elements and attributes that define the entity model exposed by the OData Service are qualified with the Entity Data Model namespace:
>
> - http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm
>
> Prior versions of CSDL used the following namespaces for EDM:
>
> - CSDL version 1.0: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm
> - CSDL version 1.1: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm
> - CSDL version 1.2: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/01/edm
> - CSDL version 2.0: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm
> - CSDL version 3.0: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm

Using the *Add Service Reference* tool in Visual Studio 2013 (optionally with [this update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/12/18/announcement-wcf-data-services-5-6-3-rtm-tools-installer-release.aspx) installed) solves the problem of generating client code for this OData service.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 (and possibly 2015) no longer support the "Add Service Reference" route: `The specified OData API cannot be added because OData APIs are now only supported with the OData Client Code Generation Tool.

For more information, please see:
https://aka.ms/odatavsclientguidance`